# Google Authentication With Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm using Swift 3 in Xcode 8 and I'm getting this door in my code. Is there any way to fix it? I appreciate if anyone can help.

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else {
                print(user?.email)
            print(user?.displayName)
```

Error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(FIRUser?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FIRAuthResultCallback?'

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block needs variable names for the returning values (user object and error) In the example below I've added the name "user" for the user object and error for the error object.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }else {
                    print(user?.email)
                print(user?.displayName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in Xcode 8 sometimes we have issue with opening the completion block. And in your code the block does not open properly. Your block should open as :

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential , completion: { (user, error) in
      //Do as per your need here  
})
```

Hope,this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't replicate the `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn` in the code. I got errors when I placed it below the SignInViewController class. 
This is a working code for iOS Google Sign I tried in the latest **Swift 4**.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) in
if error != nil {
print(error!.localizedDescription)
return
} else {
print(user?.email)
print(user?.displayName)
```